# Cannot get AWS SES production access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My company tried to get SES production access and the ticket we submitted got escalated to a Senior Review Member but it seems that we are now on a blacklist because they said that "we will not be able to assist you and there will be no further response to additional messages on this subject."

My statement was pretty concise (2 paragraphs) explaining that our company only needed to send transactional emails and has setup bounces and complaints to automatically be on a blacklist of emails. I provided a sample of the email we were going to send too and it is professional and contains an unsubscribe link. We also have a website that looks professional with a privacy policy and a checkbox that explicitly requires user consent. We planned to store the emails and blacklist of emails in AWS s3.

What did I do wrong/am missing in the statement?

Comment: We have no way of knowing.  Something about your company, its products, its history, or other red flags?  Also, please read tour to see what kind of questions can be asked and answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @DaveS We are a new company (made AWS account a couple months ago), our company sells software which is activated via a license key that we plan to put into a confirmation email upon a user purchasing our product. Those were the closest red flags I could think of.  Also sorry if I'm asking the wrong kind of question here, I'm really desperate to find support

Comment: If they have decided your company or use case does not meet their policy, and they won't tell you why or discuss it further, I don't see how we can help.  You'll need to use a different outgoing mail service.

Comment: I was expecting someone to have a similar experience and explain how they went through it. I've also tried mailjet but failed their check too so I thought it might've been something general that someone could point out.

Comment: If more than one company is rejecting you, that comes back to some problem with the company, its products, its past history.  For example products for IP theft, malware, hacking, game cheats or other cheating apps, gambling, prostitution, etc.  Or a company that appears to be non-existent or possibly impersonating another company.  I'm not saying any of that is the case, just that those are some possible reasons.